# JMX initialization order

Tags: java, jmx

I learn JMX now, but I can't understand, why my simple app works the way it works. It is sensitive for the order I "start" my server class (just println in endless loop) and I register MBean. Here is my code:

```
public interface SampleServerControllerMBean {
    public String getName();
    public void setName(String name);
    public void start();
    public void stop();
}

public class SampleServerController implements SampleServerControllerMBean {

    private SampleServer server;

    public SampleServerController(SampleServer server) {
        this.server = server;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return server.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public void setName(String name) {
        server.setName(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        server.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        server.stop();
    }
}

public class SampleServer {
    private String name = "";
    private boolean running = false;
    public SampleServer(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void start() {
        if(running) {
            System.err.println("Already running!");
            return;
        }
        running = true;
        while(running) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                running = false;
                return;
            }
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        running = false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedObjectNameException, NotCompliantMBeanException, InstanceAlreadyExistsException, MBeanRegistrationException {
        SampleServer server = new SampleServer("Hello!");
        //server.start(); // case 2
        SampleServerController serverController = new SampleServerController(server);
        MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
        ObjectName name = new ObjectName("ru.aolisov.jmx:type=SampleServerController");
        mbs.registerMBean(serverController,name);

        server.start(); // case 1
    }
}
```

In this example, here is the behaviour:
1) Case 1: register MBean, then start(). In JConsole we can see MBean and everything is working.
2) Case 2: start(), then register MBean. We don't see MBean in JConsole.

Can somebody explain, why it is sensitive to the order?

P.S. JDK 1.7.0.80, Windows 7. Running class by Intellij Idea 14.1.4, by Debug, class SampleServer.

Comment: in case 2 you are stuck in the infinite loop therefore you will not register the `mbean`

Comment: @Udy Oh, that's so stupid fault... Thanks a lot